# something about ansi_nulls

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question that we always say that null =null is false ,I want to know that when the ansi_nulls is off this statement which is "null=null" is also false? thanks

Comment: NULL=NULL evaluates to unknown rather than false with 3 valued logic. *NOT (NULL=NULL)* is not true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `ANSI_NULLS OFF`, `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `TRUE`.

With `ANSI_NULLS ON` (the default), `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `NULL`.

`NULL IS NULL` always evaluates to `TRUE`.

However, in MySQL, you cannot turn off ANSI_NULLS. You are probably thinking of MS SQL Server.

Future versions of MS SQL Server won't support `ANSI_NULLS OFF`, so I wouldn't use it.

You should leave `ANSI_NULLS ON` and use `IS NULL` to evaluate if something IS NULL.

If you're having problems remembering how NULL works by default (ANSI_NULLS ON), you should think of NULL as "**unknown**". For example, if there are two strangers in the room, their names are NULL. If your query is, "Are their names the same?" Your answer IS NULL.

Now, let's say Bob is in the room with just one stranger, whose name IS NULL. Again the answer to your query "Are their names the same?" IS NULL. Note that if you compare anything to NULL, your answer IS NULL.

Answer (score 1):

When [ansi_nulls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28SQL.80%29.aspx) is off, null=null will return true.

Eg.

```
set ansi_nulls off
select 1 where null=null
```

Gives  you:

```
1
```