# Why is MySQL (and MsSQL) not implementing ANSI_NULLS?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, null, isnull

While searching about ansi_nulls, I stubbled upon this post where it says that MySQL doesn't implement ansi_nulls, and that MsSql plans on removing it : [something about ansi_nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747279/something-about-ansi-nulls)

It was confirmed in 2017 by Microsoft about TSQL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql

But what's wrong about ANSI_NULLS? Is it bad practice to force comparison with NULL objects?

Comment: Why do you need a switch that breaks compatibility with the standard? What is the use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what's wrong about ANSI_NULLS?

It breaks compatibility with the ANSI SQL standard.

> Is it bad practice to force comparison with NULL objects?

The standard provides the standardised way to compare with `NULL`s. There is no way to not follow the standard designed approach.

Comment: I didn't know about the ANSI SQL standard, this is what I was looking for thank you!